# CQRS / Event Sourcing - transient events

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, projection, cqrs, event-sourcing

During development of my application, I found that I need to emit some events that actually don't modify the state of the aggregate, but they are needed in order to update read models (transient events?). e.g. if in my code (domain model) I hold state of hierarchy of numbers in layers like:

```
1    4    7
     5    8
3    9
```

and the read model is doing projection of events like (top number from left to right):

```
1
5
3
```

then, when I trigger event in aggregate root `RemovedNumber(1)`, and if this is the only event I trigger (since it is enough to update aggregate state), read model will not know that it needs to replace number 1 with 4.

```
? <--- SHOULD BE 4 SINCE 4 IS UNDER 1
5
3
```

So here basically, I need to trigger additionally: `NowShowNumber(4 instead of 1)`, and then read model will know to project:

```
4
5
3
```

Event `RemovedNumber(1)` should be kept in event store, since it affects internal state of aggregate. Event `NowShowNumber(4 instead of 1)` should also be stored in event store since it is affecting read model (and should be replayed on re-projecting it), but it should probably not be used during reconstruction of aggregate root from event stream.

Is this standard practice in CQRS/Event Sourcing systems? Is there some alternative solution?

Comment: First of all, you need to decide if the logic that deduces `(put 4 instead of 1)` is purely display logic or domain logic. If it affects the way in which the user can modify the Aggregate later, then it's probably not just read model stuff. The algorithm should be in the Domain and its decision reflected in the event. See @EbenRoux's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't the `Read model` know to show number `4`? 
Didn't the Aggregate emit an `AddNumber(4)` prior to `AddNumber(1)`?
Then the `Read model` has the necessary state replicated on his part, basically a stack with numbers, in order to pull the previous number and to show it.

In CQRS, in order to *help* the `Read models`, when a state changes and an `Event` is emitted, the `Aggregate` include bits of the previous state in the `Event` also.

In your case, the emitted `Event` could have the following signature `RemovedNumber( theRemovedNumber, theNewCurrentNumber)`, and in particular `RemovedNumber(1, 4)`.

Comment: But what if logic for replacing is complex business logic? Should this live in projection part of CQRS? e.g. `if(complex logic) { 4 } else { 7 }`. Seems like domain logic leaks into projection?

Comment: @bojanv55 Then include it in the same event, like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Yes. That is basically also my solution (i'm grouping transacted events in one collection).

Answer (score 1):

I call these events `out of band` events and save them to a different stream than I hydrate aggregates with.
Haven't heard anyone else doing it but haven't heard any good arguments to not do it - especially if you have a legitimate case for posting events that have no effect at all on the aggregate.

In your case if I understand your problem well enough I would just have the domain write a `TopLevelNumberChanged` event which the read model would see and process.
And obviously it would not read that event when hydrating.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see that it is at all an issue having events that don't effect changes in your projections.  Depending on the projection it may be that the projection ignores *many* events.

That being said, if you are saying that these two events go hand-in-hand you *may* need to have another look at the design / intention.  How do you know to call the second command?  Would a single command not perhaps do the trick?  The event could return the full change:

```
NumberReplacedEvent ReplaceNumber(1, 4);
```

The event would contain all the state:

```
public class NumberReplacedEvent
{
    int ReplacedNumber { get; set; }
    int WithNumber { get; set;
}
```

Comment: +1. If the algorithm that infers (added 4) from (removed 1) is in the domain, then emitted event should definitely reflect the decisions made by that algorithm.

Comment: I was talking about events that don't affect changes in Aggregate Root (now you can say that AR is also projection in a way), but by projection I assume read projection. And again, this event with 2 fields is more less similar to two events grouped in collection [Removed(1), Added(4)]

Comment: @bojanv55 so, the logic that deduces (substitute 4 to 1) from (remove 1) is purely on the read side. Fine. Then it is not an event or part of any event. You have nothing to do. Problem solved.

Comment: @bojanv55: Would it not be rather odd that you have domain events that don't effect changes in the domain?  Are these not perhaps system events then?  Even so, a projection is a read-model of your domain model.  Perhaps you can expand on that a bit since I must be missing something :(

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there's no single correct answers. CQRS / Event Sourcing is *just a tool for helping you to model your data flow*. But it's still **your** data, your business rules, your use case. In other words: Some other company could use the exact same data model, but have a different event structure, because it fits better for their use case.

### Some example:

Let's imagine we have an online shop. And every time a customer buys a product, we decrease the `inStock` value for that product. If the customer sends the product back, we increase the value.

The command is pretty simple: `BuyProduct(id: "123", amount: 4)`

For the resulting event we have (at least) 2 options:

1. `ProductBuyed(id: "123", amount: 4)` *(delta value)*
2. `ProductBuyed(id: "123", newInStockValue: 996)` *(new total value)*

*(you could also publish 4 times a simple `ProductBuyed(id: "123")` event)*

Or you can have multiple resulting events at the same time:

- `ProductBuyed(id: "123", amount: 4)`
- `InStockValueForProductChanged(id: "123", newValue: 996)`

An online shop will possibly have multiple read models that are interested in these events. The Product Page wants to display *only 996 items left!*. And the Shop Statistics Page wants to display *sold 4 items today*. Though both options (total and delta) can be useful.

**But** also both Pages could work if there's only one of both events. Then the read side must do the calculation: `oldTotal - newTotal = delta` or `oldTotal - delta = newTotal`.

**There are even more** possible solutions. For example:

1. *Checkout Service* publishes `ProductBuyed(id: "123", amount: 4)` event
2. *Stock Service* receives this event, decreases the stock and then publishes the `InStockValueForProductChanged(id: "123", newValue: 996)` event

It really depends on the needs of your business.

### My suggestions:

- **I prefer** when the write model is only responsible for managing the business rules. Get Command, validate it, publish event(s) which look pretty similar to the command contents.
- **And** the read model should be as simple as possible, too. Get Event, update model.
- If calculations have to be done, there are a few options:

  1. The calculation is part of a business rule? Then your write side has to compute the result anyway. In this case you already have written the algorithm, the CPU has done its work, and you have the resulting value for free. *(Just include the result with the published event)*
  2. The calculation is really *complex* and/or there are multiple event consumers that need the result. Then it might be better to compute it once and include the result in an event, instead of computing it *n* times for every involved event consumer. *Complex* could mean:

     - Takes a lot of time
     - Very CPU / memory intensive
     - Needs special / huge external libs (imagine you had to include some Image Processing library with every read service)
  3. The calculation is the result of a combination of a lot of different events (i.e. it's getting complex): Build an external service, which is responsible for the calculation. This way you can easily scale out by providing multiple instances of this service.
  4. If the calculation is **not** part of a business rule **and** it's simple **and** only **a single** service needs the result **or** if it's **only** relevant for the read model: Place it in the read side.

### In the end it's a tradeoff:

- Duplicate algorithms? You could have multiple event consumers written with different programming languages. Do you want to implement the algorithm multiple times?
- More network traffic / bigger event store? If you include the calculation result with the event, there's more data to store and transfer between the services. Can your infrastructure handle that?
- Can your write / read service take the additional load?